# How to manage sync on a hasMany Relationship

Tags: laravel, has-many

I have a relationship: A User hasMany Routes

So, I display the routes in a form, user can add, delete, and modify routes.

Then, he must submit the form.

What I would would like, is a way to sync old routes with new routes.

I could do:

```
foreach($routes as $route){
   ....
  $route->save();
}
```

But I would not manage deleted routes.

So, I don't like very much idea of doing : Delete all, and recreate all

Any idea how should this situation be managed?